# Creating Spark database in Azure Databricks with location to ADLS Gen 2 using ABFS driver throws an exception

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am creating a database in Azure Databricks using the abfss location in the create table statement and it throws an exception.

**Authentication to ADLS** - Session Scoped Access Key Authentication as below

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.formula1supportdl.dfs.core.windows.net", 
                dbutils.secrets.get(scope="databricks-support-scope", key="formula1supportdl-account-key"))
```

**Access Method to ADLS** - abfs driver as below

```
%sql
CREATE DATABASE f1_demo_abfss
LOCATION 'abfss://demo@formula1supportdl.dfs.core.windows.net/'
```

**Error message as below**

[image]

**Additional information**

Access to the same storage account/ container works perfectly fine if I use the cluster scoped authentication. i.e., when adding the spark configuration to the cluster configuration instead of the using in the notebook.
Specifying the location for a table as above works perfectly fine too. This is only for a problem in create database statement.

Example CREATE TABLE with the same location works perfectly fine as below

[image]

This is only a problem when trying to access the location on CREATE DATABASE statement using session scoped authentication. As I said above, cluster scoped authentication works perfectly fine. Also, CREATE TABLE with the same location works perfectly fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Stack trace as requested by Pradeep**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2302823602205408> in <cell line: 1>()
      5     display(df)
      6     return df
----> 7   _sqldf = ____databricks_percent_sql()
      8 finally:
      9   del ____databricks_percent_sql

<command-2302823602205408> in ____databricks_percent_sql()
      2   def ____databricks_percent_sql():
      3     import base64
----> 4     df = spark.sql(base64.standard_b64decode("Q1JFQVRFIERBVEFCQVNFIGYxX2RlbW9fYWJmc3MKTE9DQVRJT04gJ2FiZnNzOi8vZGVtb0Bmb3JtdWxhMXN1cHBvcnRkbC5kZnMuY29yZS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC8n").decode())
      5     display(df)
      6     return df

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     46             start = time.perf_counter()
     47             try:
---> 48                 res = func(*args, **kwargs)
     49                 logger.log_success(
     50                     module_name, class_name, function_name, time.perf_counter() - start, signature

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1117             sqlQuery = formatter.format(sqlQuery, **kwargs)
   1118         try:
-> 1119             return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self)
   1120         finally:
   1121             if len(kwargs) > 0:

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    200                 # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    201                 # JVM exception message.
--> 202                 raise converted from None
    203             else:
    204                 raise

AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Got exception: shaded.databricks.azurebfs.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.KeyProviderException Failure to initialize configuration)
```

**Also, Raised with Microsoft support here**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180145/creating-spark-database-in-azure-databricks-with-l

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace of the error message which you are experiencing?

Comment: Hi @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT - Thanks for looking into this. Please find the stack trace added to the description as requested!